# Experiencing random sporadic 504 timeouts running Laravel on DigitalOcean Kubernetes

Tags: php, laravel, networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm running a Laravel application on a DigitalOcean kubernetes cluster. The application consists of three pods running on one of three cluster nodes and has traffic routed to it via `nginx-ingress` and a DigitalOcean Load Balancer. The application is using DigitalOcean managed databases for the backend and I'm using Grafana/Prometheus for monitoring and log collation.

Each application pod consists of three containers:

1. **Laravel Application** (PHP-FPM and Nginx sidecar) - *I'm aware it's bad practice to group multiple services together in a single pod but I did this for simplicity until I get my head around the K8s architecture. I was experiencing some major performance issues with using shared volumes for both the `nginx` and `fpm` containers to access the codebase. Pods were taking minutes to spin up because the files had to be copied from the Docker image to the shared volume. (If anyone has a better solution to this then I'm all ears!)*
2. **Nginx Metrics**
3. **FPM Metrics**

I'm using Helm3/Flux to deploy the application and the `.yaml` files look like this:

**Ingress:**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "app.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "50m"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - [REDACTED].com
      secretName: app-tls
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: {{ .Values.ingress.path }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ template "app.fullname" . }}
              servicePort: http
```

**Service**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "app.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - port: 9253
      targetPort: 9253
      protocol: TCP
      name: fpmmetrics
    - port: 9113
      targetPort: 9113
      protocol: TCP
      name: nginxmetrics
  selector:
    app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

With the above config I'm able to access the site via the public hostname. The vast majority of the time the site performs as expected, however around one in 10 requests never resolve and returns a `504` if I leave it long enough. If I initiate a refresh before the `504` is returned, chances are that the page loads almost instantly.

I'm aware that I haven't given enough details for anyone to diagnose this but I'm at a loss where to start debugging this. I've checked the logs and nothing stands out as abnormal and when the site does load it performs as expected which leads me to believe that it's an ingress/networking issue.

Here's the stats from my ingress controller that shows the slow response time for `.99` and the occasional `504`.

How would I go about starting to diagnose this?

[image: ingress controller metrics]

Comment: Have you tried to specify proxy read,send and connect-timeout annotations in your k8s ingress as mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3976#issuecomment-639408528)? Additionally you could take a look at this stackoverflow post about [504 with aws](https://serverfault.com/questions/963116/nginx-ingress-504-timeout-eks-with-elb-connected-to-nginx-ingress), couldn´t find anything specific for digital ocean.